# Server java app not working on a local connection

Tags: java, dynamic, dns, raspberry-pi, serversocket

hi have at home a rasperry pi running a server java app, connected to de router with the dynamic DNS configured and the in/out communication ports openned.
When i run the android apication client througt 4g everithing is working sucessfull. But when i run the same app connected to the wifi on my local net, where the server are running,  the server application looks like death.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

[router config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkLgm.png)

Comment: Is possible to block on raspbian a connection comming from especific dns?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to your DNS. If you are connected using your wifi, you have to return a local IP-Address. Do you have any chance of configuring your router to return the raspberries local IP-Address for wifi-clients?
Take a look here: [link](https://www.dyncommunity.com/questions/26377/i-cant-access-my-dyndns-from-local-network.html)

Comment: I'm not sure how to config router to return the local IP.Address. The link below takes me to the edit secction of this post.

Comment: Editing the host file is working on windows laptop. It is a quite dificult to edit the host file on android device. Root needed. I need to hack my phone? There's no other way.

Comment: you can check for `android dns server app` in google. you could use the dns changer and a local dns server.

Comment: is possible to block on raspbian a connection from specific dns ?

Comment: what exactly do you need? do you only want to allow local connections?

Comment: I want the server app don't stop running when i connect from local network. And that is what happens when i run the client app connected to wifi at home.

Comment: The client app is configured to connect to dns (dyn dns) and this dns redirect to my router public ip and the router redirect to the server app running on raspberry pi. And ip from server and client are the same. Maybe is this the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, even if it is not very elegant, is adding the following conditions to your code:

- If there is an error connecting to the Dyn DNS, try to connect to the local IP address. (In case you are in the Wifi LAN)
- If the local IP address fails, try again your Dyn DNS (in case the user is a real user with real communication problems)

(repeat until the connection is successful)

You can also identify your testing devices (using Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID, or the IMEI) and use the local IP only for them. Another option is making the URL configurable (with a hidden option for example).

Comment: I'm thinking about a re-code solution to block connections from specific dns. For me is not a problem if i can not connect from local devices, the problem is that this local connections block the server app.

Answer (score 0):

Because of my app can run local, only needs to connect to server for updates. I have block the connection on the server app if the ip from client and server are equals.

At the moment is the best solution to keep the server app running properly.

```
 URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
 InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream()));


 String ip = in.readLine(); 


    try {


        SSLServerSocketFactory sslFactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLServerSocket ss = (SSLServerSocket) sslFactory.createServerSocket(PORT);


        int idSession = 0; 
        while (true) {

            SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)ss.accept();



            if(socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress().equals(ip)){
                if (socket != null && !socket.isClosed()) {

            socket.close();
        }
            }

            ((ServidorThread) new ServidorThread(socket, idSession)).start();
            idSession++;

        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```